# How to order ng-repeat with a function a use button to change the order parameter in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a little bug while trying to use angularjs table.

```
         tr     
              th
                a(href='', ng-click="predicate = 'id'; reverse=!reverse") Id
              th
                a(href='', ng-click="predicate = 'number'; reverse=!reverse")
              th
                a(href='', ng-click="predicate ='urlGlobalCount'; reverse=!reverse") Total
        tr(ng-repeat='url in URLList | orderBy:predicate:reverse' ng-init="addOne(url)")
              td {{$index + 1}}   
              td {{url.number}}
              td {{urlGlobalCount(url)}}
```

The funtion urlGlobalCount return a number

```
$scope.urlGlobalCount = function(item) {
   return *somenumber*
};
```

When i try to order by urlGlobalCount it's not working.

If i change the code to this :

```
       tr(ng-repeat='url in URLList | orderBy:urlGlobalCount :reverse' ng-init="addOne(url)")
```

ordering by urlGlobalCount function work fine.

Any idea to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the actual function in your click, not a string of the function. Change:

```
ng-click="predicate ='urlGlobalCount';
```

to:

```
ng-click="predicate =urlGlobalCount;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$scope.predicateFn = function(item) {
    return $scope.predicate === 'urlGlobalCount' ?
      $scope.urlGlobalCount(item) : item[$scope.predicate];
};

ng-repeat='url in URLList | orderBy:predicateFn:reverse'
```